Powershell is not excluding the right values to delete the images from the azure repository
I'm having powershell script as below but it is not working as expected trying to retrieve images and delete the non running images from the acr .
I was able to pull the images but not able to delete them as per my requirement
it should exclude the tags from $tagsToExclude in $tagsToDelete
$alltags = foreach ($env in $environment) {
    # Get the list of images from k8s cluster
    $tags = az aks command invoke --resource-group test-$env --name test-$env --command "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}' | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c"
    # Skip the first line comments from PowerShell
    $deletefirstline = $tags | Select-Object -Skip 1
    # Remove the count of the images
    $removecount = $deletefirstline -replace '^\S*\s+'
    # Filter the image tags with "/i;" in the name and extract the tags
    $removecount | Where-Object { $_ -like "*/ip-*" } | ForEach-Object {
        # Extract the image name and version
        $nameVersion = $_ -split '[:/]'
        # Output the image name and version
        "$($nameVersion[2]), $($nameVersion[3])"
    }
}

$groupedData = $alltags | ForEach-Object {
    $parts = $_ -split ', '
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Key = $parts[0]; Value = $parts[1] }
} | Group-Object -Property Key

# Store the output in a variable
$sortedtags = $groupedData | ForEach-Object {
    $key = $_.Name
    $values = $_.Group | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }
    "$key = " + ($values -join "`n")
}

# Extract only the values for ip-id
$ipIdOutput = $sortedtags | Where-Object { $_ -like "ip-id*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "ip-id = ", ""
}

# Extract only the values for ip-data
$ipDataOutput = $sortedtags | Where-Object { $_ -like "ip-data*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "ip-data = ", ""
}

# Extract only the values for ip-hardwave
$ipHardwaveOutput = $sortedtags | Where-Object { $_ -like "ip-hardwave*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "ip-hardwave = ", ""
}

# Extract only the values for ip-tube
$ipTubeOutput = $sortedtags | Where-Object { $_ -like "ip-tube*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "ip-tube = ", ""
}

# Print the ip-id values
$ipIdOutput = $ipIdOutput | ForEach-Object { "latest`n" + ($_ -replace '","', "`n" -replace '"', "") }
$ipDataOutput = $ipDataOutput | ForEach-Object { "latest`n" + ($_ -replace '","', "`n" -replace '"', "") }
$ipHardwaveOutput = $ipHardwaveOutput | ForEach-Object { "latest`n" + ($_ -replace '","', "`n" -replace '"', "") }
$ipTubeOutput = $ipTubeOutput | ForEach-Object { "latest`n" + ($_ -replace '","', "`n" -replace '"', "") }


$registryName = "testcontainers001"
$repositoryName = "org/ip-hardwave"
$tagsToExclude = $ipHardwaveOutput


# List the tags in the repository
$tagslist = az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repositoryName --output table


$ipHardwaveOutput.GetType()
$tagsToExclude.GetType()

# Convert $tagslist to an array of strings
$tagsArray = $tagslist -split "`n"

$ipHardwaveOutput.GetType()
$tagsToExclude.GetType()

# Ensure both $tagsArray and $tagsToExclude are trimmed and formatted correctly
$tagsArray = $tagsArray | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
$tagsToExclude = $tagsToExclude | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

# Debugging output to check the contents of $tagsArray and $tagsToExclude
Write-Output "Tags Array:"
Write-Output $tagsArray
Write-Output "Tags to Exclude:"
Write-Output $tagsToExclude

# Filter tags to exclude the specified ones
$tagsToDelete = $tagsArray | Where-Object { $tagsToExclude -notcontains $_ }

# Debugging output to check the contents of $tagsToDelete
Write-Output "Tags to Delete:"
Write-Output $tagsToDelete

# Delete the remaining tags
foreach ($tag in $tagsToDelete) {
    $imageToDelete = "$($repositoryName):$($tag)"
    Write-Output $imageToDelete
    #az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $imageToDelete --yes --dry-run
}


Having output as below
Tags to Exclude:
latest
develop-20210911.1
20210904.1
20210904.1

Tags to Delete:
20210605.1
20210605.3
20210828.5
20210828.8
20210828.9
20210829.1
20210829.2
20210829.3
20210829.5
20210830.1
20210830.2
20210904.1
20210904.2
20210905.1
20210905.2
20210905.3
20210906.1
20210906.2
20210909.1
20210910.1
20210910.2
develop-20210911.1
latest



org/ip-hardwave:20210605.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210605.3
org/ip-hardwave:20210828.5
org/ip-hardwave:20210828.8
org/ip-hardwave:20210828.9
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.3
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.5
org/ip-hardwave:20210830.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210830.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210904.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210904.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210905.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210905.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210905.3
org/ip-hardwave:20210906.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210906.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210909.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210910.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210910.2
org/ip-hardwave:develop-20210911.1
org/ip-hardwave:latest

expecting output as below
org/ip-hardwave:20210605.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210605.3
org/ip-hardwave:20210828.5
org/ip-hardwave:20210828.8
org/ip-hardwave:20210828.9
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.3
org/ip-hardwave:20210829.5
org/ip-hardwave:20210830.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210830.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210904.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210905.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210905.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210905.3
org/ip-hardwave:20210906.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210906.2
org/ip-hardwave:20210909.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210910.1
org/ip-hardwave:20210910.2


Your sample output has a Result header and no :'s - yet Result is nowhere to be found in the script, and you're definitely adding a : in all the tags to delete in the last loop. Are you sure the output you've shown is actually what you get?

I'm sure about the output and I'm not sure from where Result is coming from it's no where I added but I would be glad @MathiasR.Jessen if you get the problem and show some solution as always

I got it it is coming from the az command
List the tags in the repository
$tagslist = az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repositoryName --output table

Please share the output from the script instead of the output from az acr ... - the tag list obviously won't update as long as you have commented out az acr repository delete ...

I was able to avoid result with Select-Object -Skip 2 updated the question with output

Ahh, I see now. $tagsToExclude is one big string instead of an array. Do $tagsToExclude = $tagsToExclude -split '\r?\n'before filtering, and it'll work

Rather than replacing item delimiters with literal newline characters, split the input data into arrays instead.
For example, change:
$ipIdOutput = $sortedtags | Where-Object { $_ -like "ip-id*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "ip-id = ", ""
}

to:
$ipIdOutput = @($sortedtags | Where-Object { $_ -like "ip-id*" } | ForEach-Object {
    # remove key and split on comma
    $values = $_ -replace "ip-id = ", "" -split ','
    # trim leading/trailing whitespace, then remove leading/trailing quotes from each value
    $values |ForEach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace '^"(.*)"$','$1'}
})

and then replace the following:
$ipIdOutput = $ipIdOutput | ForEach-Object { "latest`n" + ($_ -replace '","', "`n" -replace '"', "") }

with:
# insert "latest" tag on top
$ipIdOutput = @('latest';$ipIdOutput)

Repeat for $ipDataOutput, $ipHardwaveOutput and $ipTubeOutput, and you're done.
$tagsToExclude gets its value from $ipHardwaveOutput, so by turning that into a proper array containing individual values as separate strings you'll incidentally also solve the filtering problem.
